# SQLITE3 + execute Insert

Tags: sqlite

Trying to execute insert an item coming from a list:`

> > > item=u'Sunil Goyal'
> > >
> > > c.execute('''INSERT INTO bpersons(person_name) VALUES (?)''',item)`

is simple enough, but it returns

> Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 11 supplied.

Clearly instead of reading item as one element, it is reading characters. There is no problem with the earlier code which returns this list:

```
>>> if meta[7]:#bcoz list could be empty also
    for item in meta[7]:
        print item
```

Sunil Goyal

Rehan Yar Khan

Khan

Kae Capital

Ashish Shankar

Karthik Reddy

Feroze Azeez

> > > len(meta[7])
> > >       7

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`insert` is looking for an iterable [(documentation)](https://pysqlite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) and this succeeds because your unicode string is an iterable, but you should put it inside of a tuple or list to be handled properly by sqlite3.

```
c.execute('''INSERT INTO bpersons(person_name) VALUES (?)''',(item,))`
```

Comment: Thanks. I was mixing up this syntax in my head:`INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)
VALUES (1, 'Paul', 32, 'California', 20000.00 );`. Why this difference, tho? COMPANY.ADDRESS will read 'California' but (?,?,?,?,?) will not?